# How to create a Elixir node without using IEx?

Tags: elixir

When using Elixir’s interactive shell IEx, I can create a node by command:

```
iex --sname node_name
```

But how can I create a node by code, then run the code by:

```
elixir code.exs
```

There are some function like node(), but it seems that those function just return a node existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
elixir --sname node_name
```

Generally, you pass the node name so that everything starts up knowing its own name. However, it is apparently also possible to set the name while running with the Erlang net_kernel module, as described in the answer to [How set Erlang node name...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14079694/1220269)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an Erlang release you can use the `vm.args` file.  [This](https://hexdocs.pm/exrm/extra-release-configuration.html) is how you do it if using `exrm` to build a release.

Answer (score 0):

I think what @Nai means is to create a node inside an Elixir application or script. In that case, it is possible to create a node using:

```
Node.start(:"your_node_name")
```

Then you can set the cookie with:

```
Node.set_cookie(:your_security_cookie)
```

There is a set of useful functions to work with nodes in Elixir in the module [Node](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.14.4/Node.html).

> There are some function like node(), but it seems that those function just return a node existed.

About it, `node()` is a function of the Elixir's kernel ([documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.14.4/Kernel.html#node/0)) that returns the node in which you are working and, and if your local node isn't alive, it returns `:nonode@nohost`. It also can return the node in which a PID, reference or port is running using it `node(arg)`, where `arg` is the PID, reference or port.